# how to deploy heroku with an existing an git repository

Tags: git, heroku

I have been working on a repository and am now pushing it to heroku.  I went through heroku for a guide    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

I checked to make sure I had the git and heroku configuration.

```
git remote -v
```

I get back a heroku config and a git config for fetch and push

```
heroku git:remote -a path name
```

However, I get back "couldn't find that app"   So I typed

```
heroku apps
```

My app is not there.   So I am missing something.  I followed the directions and can verify my remote.  Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Did you push your repository? `git push heroku master`

Comment: Yeah, I am getting a fatal on that part as well.  Trying to figure out what step I am missing.  not sure if i can rm the file then redo it.

Comment: In your question you said `heroku git:remote -a -path name` - where did you take it from? I am pretty sure it should be `-a app_name` - the one you got when you did `heroku create`

Comment: i am getting heroku https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-escarpment-1894.git.  This seems correct.  I am inserting  heroku git:remote -a sleepy-escarpment-1894

Comment: What error do you see when you try to push?

Comment: I keep getting fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-escarpment-1894.git/' not found

Comment: Please add the output of your `git remote -v`

Comment: heroku https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-escarpment-1894.git (fetch)
heroku https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-escarpment-1894.git (push)
origin https://github.com/winnemucca/capital-machinery.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/winnemucca/capital-machinery.git (push)

Answer (score 5):

First remove the heroku remote

```
git remote rm heroku
```

Add it again correctly

```
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/sleepy-escarpment-1894.git
```

Then push your app

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: I just tried that as well.  I got the same response.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  I am going through the steps but i have done them all.  Thanks for your help though

Comment: package.json  I did not add a space between node and ./app.js  "start": "node ./app.js"